# Why is the unemployment ratio considered to be double in this context?

Tags: arithmetic, percentages

Question :

"If 98 out of 100 children were in school before, but now 96 in 100 are enrolled, that is a fall in enrollment rate of 2% (98%-96%=2%). You could also say the number of unenrolled children doubled (increased by 100%, 2x2% = 4%)."

Doubt:

How has the unenrolled children doubled with the the given value? What I really do not understand is why are they taking 2 % as the basis for such calculations. A detailed insight into this might help me to understand the problem.

Comment: Compare before $\,\frac{100-98}{100}=2\%\,$ vs. after $\,\frac{100-96}{100}=4\%\,$.

Comment: Suppose these statistics describe enrollments in a region where $100{,}000$ children live. Previously, $98{,}000$ of these children were in school and $2000$ were not enrolled. Now $96{,}000$ of these children are in school and $4000$ are not enrolled. $4000$ is twice as many as $2000.$